# Why wont jquery `load` include script files if i set a `div` to be loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im after an answer as to why this does this more than a solution.

Why will this include the script tags that load js files within the page being loaded..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nav ul li label").on("click", function(){
        var a = $(this).attr("id");
        $("#mainCalcHolder").load(a + ".php");
    });
});
```

and this not include the script tags that load js files that are purposely inside the "getMe" div?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nav ul li label").on("click", function(){
        var a = $(this).attr("id");
        $("#mainCalcHolder").load(a + ".php #getMe");
    });
});
```

If anyone could give me a brief explanation I'd appreciate it

Comment: Dumb question... but are you sure the page you are fetching has a `id="getMe"` included? It looks like it should be working [docs here](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments)

Comment: @TheIronDeveloper yes it has, the html is loading in ok but the script tags that are meant to come with and make it work dont.

Comment: Mind sharing an example DOM of the page that is being loaded? My best guess is jQuery is having issues parsing the document for some raison.

Comment: @TheIronDeveloper removing the space made it work, but everywhere  had looked included a space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is the space between `.php` and `#getMe`. Try removing it:

```
$("#mainCalcHolder").load(a + ".php#getMe");
```

EDIT: as specified in the comments, removing the space loads the whole page instead of just the fragment, so the code snippet is equivalent to not specifying the `#getMe` part at all.

The reason why it wasn't working for you before is that your content consists of a script, which is stripped when loading a fragment (as specified in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments)) but is executed when loading the full page.

Comment: jQuery docs show a space in between. http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments

Comment: ty I looked around and everywhere had the space but removing it worked?

Comment: The problem is that when loading a page fragment, the scripts will not be loaded. Check the documentation linked by TheIronDeveloper in the above comment. By requesting the whole page, the scripts in it are executed, so in this case it works. Note that removing the space in the end is the same as removing the `#getMe` part, so the code sample becomes equivalent to the first one in your original post.

Answer (score -1):

`load` accepts three parameters ([doc](http://api.jquery.com/load/)), the first one is the url to load. in your second case you are passing a wrong parameter: `a + ".php #getMe"`, which is a url, followed by a space (which is invalid in a url) followed by an identifier. Not sure what is the purpose of the `#getMe` div

Comment: the "getMe" div is to say which part of the page i want to load